# celery on kubernetes execute task 15 minutes after receive

Tags: kubernetes, celery, django-celery

try to migrate my app `django/celery` in nomad(hashicorp) to Kubernetes, and jobs with `@shared_task()` it's executed after 15 min at receiving message

I don't see anything in stats or status, Redis connection is OK

I see the task in flower, but it remains started during 15min

```
Received    2021-09-28 20:30:56.387649 UTC
Started     2021-09-28 20:30:56.390532 UTC
Succeeded   2021-09-28 20:46:00.556030 UTC

Received    2021-09-28 21:18:43.436750 UTC
Started     2021-09-28 21:18:43.441041 UTC
Succeeded   2021-09-28 21:33:49.391542 UTC

Celery version is 4.4.2
```

Any resolution to this problem?

Comment: Weak allocated machine/cluster resources?

Comment: Hi, i have try with and without , nothing change

Answer (score 0):

fixed, it's based on redis key cache with setex
thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).